# What font and size is used under app icons on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, text, font-size

I was wondering what font type and size Apple uses underneath the app icons on the home screen on the iPhone. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score -2):

There is no boundation of font size, but they check your  app icon size which should be 57*57 for main icon and 114*114 for retina display.

Comment: They asked about font size and type, not icon size.